# JavaScript: Arrow Function with Destruction?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), the following code is used as an example of how arrow functions are used to write shorter functions.

```
var materials = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

materials.map(function(material) { 
  return material.length; 
}); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

materials.map((material) => {
  return material.length;
}); // [8, 6, 7, 9]

materials.map(({length}) => length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

I understand the two first. What exactly is going on in the last function?

Is it an ES6 object destructuring assignment (i.e. when a material String object is received as an argument from map, the length property of that string is destructured into a length variable, then returned by the arrow function)?

Comment: Destructuring, yes. Destruction, definitely no.

Comment: It's not an assignment but a parameter declaration, but yes it's the same destructuring syntax and it works the same as in an assignment expression.

Comment: String objects have a length property. So, that object property is getting unpacked: =>  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at the first element of the iteration with `'Hydrogen'` as element for [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

`'Hydrogen'` has a length property, because it is a string, which has a length property. This value is taken and assigned to `length` variable and later used in the callback as return value for a new array.

```js
var { length } = 'Hydrogen';

console.log(length);
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is destructuring.

`material` is an object and you can get his properties in a neater and readable way.

instead of doing this:

```
materials.map((material) => {
  return material.length;
});
```

you use ES6 to extract `{ length }` property out of the `material` object, and you're getting this:

```
materials.map(({length}) => length);
```

Also, in an arrow function you don't have to wrap the function with `{}`, if its a one-liner, and if you don't wrap it with `{}` you can also omit the `return` keyword, the function will return it automatically.

You can read more about it here:

https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/

Answer (score -3):

`{length}` is the `.length` of the elements of the array, e.g., `"Hydrogen"` `.length` is `8`