# Fetch API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to render a list from an API but the problem is I am able to console.log the element I want to render but I am not able to render it into the HTML side below is the code.
when I use `<li>${element}</li>` it gives an error.

```js
const url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"
const url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2"
const url3 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3"
const fData = document.getElementById('fData')

async function fetchApis() {
  const results = await Promise.all([fetch(url1), fetch(url2), fetch(url3)])
  const responseAll = results.map(result => result.json())
  const finalData = await Promise.all(responseAll)
  console.log(finalData)
  const finalDataToString = finalData.map(function(arraydata) {
    return arraydata.name
  })
  fData.innerHTML = `${finalDataToString.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element)
   })}`
}
fetchApis()
```

```html
<ul id="fData"></ul>
```

Comment: Please always include error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the code down a little to make your life easier.

1. Put the URLs in an array to start with.
2. `map` over the URLs array and call `apiCall` on each iteration to return an array of promises.
3. `await Promise.all(promises)`.
4. You now have an array of data objects. `map` over that array and return the HTML you want in a template string.
5. Finally add that HTML string to the element (which should be a `ul` or `ol` if you want to return list items.

```js
// Return a promise of data to come
function apiCall(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

async function getData(urls) {

  // `map` over the urls array and for each iteration
  // call `apiCall`. An array of promises is returned
  const promises = urls.map(apiCall);

  // Get the data from the promises
  const data = await Promise.all(promises);

  // Finally `map` over the array of objects and return
  // a template string with the object name value
  return data.map(obj => `<li>${obj.name}</li>`).join('');
}

// `await` the call to `getData`, and then
// add the HTML to the list element
async function main(el, urls) {
  const html = await getData(urls);
  el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

const urls = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3'
];

const el = document.querySelector('#fData');

main(el, urls);
```

```html
<ul id="fData"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only does a console.log, you do not wrap in LI

Here I use an [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

And I get the name using [destruct in an arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371958/javascript-arrow-function-with-destruction)

```js
const url1 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"
const url2 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2"
const url3 = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3"
const fData = document.getElementById('fData')

async function fetchApis() {
  const results = await Promise.all([fetch(url1), fetch(url2), fetch(url3)])
  const responseAll = results.map(result => result.json())
  const finalData = await Promise.all(responseAll)
  // finalData contains an array of all data fetched
  // create an array of name wrapped in LI and join with spaces
  fData.innerHTML = finalData.map(({name}) => `<li>${name}</li>`).join("")
}
fetchApis()
```

```html
<ul id="fData"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helps a lot, it works, and would have been amazing if you had explained it a little bit in detail considering that I am a beginner however I really appreciate the gesture.

Comment: See updated comments